# Get python script filename by PID using shell_exec

Tags: python, php, linux

### **Problem**

I am using PHP to interact with a multitude of Python services.

This is how PHP uses bash to start processes and get PID:

```
$created_pid= shell_exec("nohup python3.8 -u $python_filename >> $log_filename & echo $!");
echo json_encode([
    "resolved"=>true,
    "pid"=>trim($created_pid)
]);
```

This perfectly logs the started PID. However, I would like to also write a function that checks if the PID is still active and if it's associated with the correct script contained in `$python_filename`.

### What I tried

So let's suppose `$python_filename = "test.py"` and `$created_pid = 29780`

I have tried using this command to retrieve process info based on PID:

```
$ ps -p 29780
```

Which outputs:

```
29780 pts/0    00:00:00 python3.8
```

Yeah, it's telling me it's a `python3.8` process, and I'm happy but not satisfied. I need to know if, in particular, it's the `test.py` script.

---

On the other hand, if I execute:

```
$ ps -ef | grep "python"
```

Which outputs something that is too hard to **parse**:

```
root     29780 29615  0 17:26 pts/0    00:00:00 python3.8 -u test.py
```

So **this** is basically close to the **solution** that I'm expecting. What I'm looking for is just a cleaner output of the last bash command, which only contains `test.py`.

Comment: `kill -0 <pid>` checks if a process is alive.

Comment: @jordann but it does not tell me if it's `test.py` python filename running under that process or it's another script :)

Comment: You probably have a better chance of winning the lottery than hitting a race condition where the pid is currently being reused by another process. Around 65k other processes need to come and go before it will reuse that PID again.

Comment: @jordanm in my infrastructure I store py script filenames and relative PID in the database, for later checking on the service. The process is on nohup & so it will stay in the background without changing the PID, most likely.

Comment: the output is not **that** hard to parse, you want just the last field. try `ps -p 5771 -f | awk 'NR == 2 { print $NF }'` where `5771` is your pid

Comment: @MarcoLucidi Thank you, it works. Can you post an answer also explaining what it does and if it works with other filenames (i.e `python_test_v3.py`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A "quick and dirty" solution is to just extract the last "field" in the command string since we know that the filename is in that position:

```
$ python test.py &
[1] 8040
$ ps -p 8040 --no-headers -o cmd | awk '{ print $NF }'
test.py
$
```

we tell `ps` to print just the command string of the process without the columns header (`ps -p 8040 --no-headers -o cmd`) and we tell `awk` to extract just the last space separate field of the input line (`awk '{ print $NF }'`). `$NF` is an automatic variable in `awk` which holds the "number of fields" in the current record.

This will fail if your filenames contain spaces since `awk` interprets spaces as field separator by default:

```
$ mv test.py test\ with\ spaces.py
$ python test\ with\ spaces.py &
[1] 9033
$ ps -p 9033 --no-headers -o cmd | awk '{ print $NF }'
spaces.py
$
```

As I said, this is a quick and dirty solution slightly improved from my first attempt in the comments.

## EDIT

After some thinking, I may have found a better solution more specific to the "still running check" rather than to the "extract script filename from command".

Since you know and store the PID -> filename association you could grep for the file name in the command string and just check the exit code of grep: `0` match, running; `1` no match, not running.

```
ps -p 11873 -o cmd | grep -q 'test with spaces.py'
```

e.g.

```
$ python test\ with\ spaces.py &
[4] 11873
$ ps -p 11873 -o cmd | grep -q 'test with spaces.py' && echo running || echo not running
running
$ ps -p 999 -o cmd | grep -q 'test with spaces.py' && echo running || echo not running
not running
$
```

Comment: Awesome solution! The last solution did it even better! You def know bash.